# Why are former SS Engineers and Scientists who worked for NASA still honored?

Tags: united-states, nazi-germany

This is a very serious question for me and I hope this will be treated with seriousness. One can look up on the NASA website the biography of, for example, [Debus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_H._Debus) who was a member of the SS. There is zero mention of this or even clear indication that he fought against the USA during WW2. It is my understanding that he is among former SS who have buildings and awards named for them. The removal of Confederate statues of people who I think are clearly less reprehensible and much further removed in time from the present. What prospect is there of NASA removing the names of these fascists from such awards, etc. or at least giving an accurate account of their nazi past?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is actually a history question. Why they are not currently considered as war criminals is a question of politics and possibly sociology and/or law. How they will be considered in the future is a matter of speculation.

Comment: @SteveBird: I understand your point, it is sort of a metahistory question, perhaps.

Comment: Out of history branches only ethnogenesis of Gumilev considers morals, but either against concrete rules of the concrete society, or, with an attempt for objectivity, from the point of view: what was the direction of influence of that considered deed on the age of the ethnicum?

Comment: Don't forget, that SS practices were quite common in human history, but only Germans were punished somehow for that.  Man is still a dirty and agressive ape. Trying to "get real". It is too wide-spread.

Comment: While you may have a pretty good point here, I voted to close because this website is not here for people to make points. We are for asking and answering questions about history. Reading through this I don't think you are looking for any information about the history of this matter.

Comment: Note that in general, if your question is posed in the present tense, its most likely off-topic. This one IMHO nearly skates in due by virtue of being historiography. However, it essentially seems to boil down to "why are people today doing X, when they are also doing Y?", and thus cannot really be answered merely by relating the history of the matter.

Comment: ...that being said, there probably is room here somewhere for a good question about the postwar race to secure the services of ex-Nazi rocket engineers, and how much they ended up contributing. Its a really interesting story.

Comment: Some people were members of NSDAP and/or SS for career reasons. Debus was, _apparently_, such a case. Looks like he did not commit any crimes personally. Since he later contributed to the US space program, removing his name from the NASA history would be unfair.

Comment: Too emotional, too subjective for me to vote reopen.

Comment: @sds: Don't eliminate his name, but don't whitewash his past, especially if the SS is really just kind of like the Boy Scouts (with mass murder but so what?)

Answer (score 2):

That's not NASA's duty, and tbh it's not needed. All these people were heavily vetted and cleared of war crimes before being granted US citizenship and coming to work at NACA (later NASA).

They're not war criminals in the same way that your average German soldier returning from the front in 1945 was not a war criminal.

Did some do things they in hindsight probably weren't proud of during the war? No doubt. But then again so do most people who end up involved in armed conflict.

Not everyone who was an SS man was a lunatic mindless killing machine revelling in slaughtering innocent victims in the most gruesome ways.
In fact most of them weren't, they were just normal people recruited in a massive machine of an organisation that provided them with jobs that were generally better paid, with better facilities, and less threat of ending up conscripted to the eastern front, than other opportunities.
It was similar to taking a job at the CIA now, or at MIT or Berkeley university. All have done things that in hindsight weren't nice (including medical experiments on human beings...), but we're not calling for the public erasure of the achievements of anyone who worked there while those things were going on.

Comment: @Jeff no BS in it at all. Just because you don't like the truth doesn't make it any less true.

Comment: There is no plausible way in which these guys did not know what was going on with slave labor. But: If membership in the SS does not automatically make one a piece of shit, then why not mention it in the bio just like what university Debus went to? Do you think you are being consistent?

Comment: Just because I may know something criminal goes on in the organisation I'm a member of doesn't mean I'm a criminal. Get real. I've worked for a company I worked for was involved in insider trading at stock markets, without my knowledge though I kinda suspected. That doesn't mean I'm guilty of insider trading.

Comment: Please stop -- I can't remain civil on this.

Comment: @jwenting recruited? Are you OK? The SS members were strictly selected and all of them were volunteers. Mostly of them were not lunatic, really, they were simply moral invalids, who simply built their carrieers on the bones of other people. They simply 'got real'. And in any generation there are enough of such people. And of course, no one of such people should be honoured in any way. BTW, you too, don't want to be honoured for work in that unlawful company, do you?

Comment: @Gangnus look up the meaning of "recruited". Yes, they were selected, just like any employer selects their employees. And yes, many of them were just doing a job, happy to have a job where they were immune from the horrors of the eastern front (which were all too visible in German town and cities when the shot up soldiers came home as early as 1943). Most of them weren't moral invalids, they were just party members in good standing (which was the only hard requirement for SS membership for all members, for specific functions of course other things were needed, just like for any job).

Comment: @jwenting For you the Nazist party member with a good standing is not a moral invalid? Who are you, then?

Comment: Downvoted for the last paragraph. Both NSDAP and SS were declared "criminal organizations" and mere membership in them was therefore a crime.